# div table-responsive image

Tags: css, html

I created a div based table. I'm trying to take a image, put it in top left table cell and make it responsive. I've made it responsive, but its not in the table cell I want it to be. Any help?

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/benjones337/3c4fkb78/18/

HTML

```
    <div class="hmTable">
        <div class="hmTableRow">
            <div class="hmTableCell"><p class="rspimg1"></p></div>
            <div class="hmTableCell"><p class="rspimg2"></p></div>
        </div>
        <div class="hmTableRow">
            <div class="hmTableCell">textholder</div>
            <div class="hmTableCell">textholder</div>
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .hmTable { 
                margin: 0 auto; /* or margin: 0 auto 0 auto */
                display: table;
                width: 50%;

        }
.hmTableRow {
                display: table-row;
        }

.hmTableCell, .hmTableHead {
                display: table-cell;
                width: 50%;
        height:100%;
                border: 1px solid #999999;
          position:relative;


        }

.hmTableBody {
                display: table-row-group;
        }
.rspimg1{
      background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/39/Red_triangle_with_thick_white_border.svg/1152px-Red_triangle_with_thick_white_border.svg.png");
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-size:100% 100%;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      position:absolute;

 }

.rspnimg2{

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `background-image`, the `div` doesn't grow with the image, so you will need to give it a height/width, either to the cell or the image `div` (btw, I changed your `p` to `div`, as `p` is for text rather than image).

Below sample I'm pretty sure look close to what you are after, and If not, drop me a comment and I'll fix it for you.

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.hmTable { 
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  width: 50%;
  height: 30%;
}
.hmTableRow {
  display: table-row;
  height: 10%;
}
.hmTableCell, .hmTableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 50%;
  height:100%;
  border: 1px solid #999999;             
}
.rspimg1{
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/3/39/Red_triangle_with_thick_white_border.svg/1152px-Red_triangle_with_thick_white_border.svg.png") center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.rspnimg2{
}
```

```html
<div class="hmTable">
  <div class="hmTableRow">
    <div class="hmTableCell">
      <div class="rspimg1">triangle</div>
    </div>
    <div class="hmTableCell">
      <div class="rspimg2">square</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="hmTableRow">
    <div class="hmTableCell">textholder</div>
    <div class="hmTableCell">textholder</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `position:absolute` or add `top:0` to `.rspimg1`.
[Result](https://jsfiddle.net/3c4fkb78/19/)